# D3.js Force directed graph example not working for alternate data set

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph, force-layout

I'm using this example from D3.js: 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I used the exact same data set, and it works.

Now, when I change it with my data set, it fails with the error:

```
d3.v4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string '4'
    at n (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at d3.v4.min.js:2
    at be.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at e (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at n (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at vn (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at _n (d3.v4.min.js:2)
```

The D3 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("mis2.js", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

The data set (that fails):

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "group": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "group": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "group": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "group": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "group": 5
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "group": 6
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "group": 7
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "group": 8
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "group": 9
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "group": 10
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": "1",
      "target": "1",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "source": "3",
      "target": "3",
      "value": "3"
    },
    {
      "source": "5",
      "target": "4",
      "value": "5"
    },
    {
      "source": "5",
      "target": "5",
      "value": "5"
    },
    {
      "source": "7",
      "target": "7",
      "value": "7"
    },
    {
      "source": "10",
      "target": "5",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "source": "10",
      "target": "10",
      "value": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have an element with the id `4` but you do have a link with the target `4`...

Comment: Just had a look at the huge data set (this was a subset). You're right, 4 is missing! It's a public data set, with an error!

Comment: If you post that as an answer, you can get points.